# Configure nginx with multiple locations in the same server

Tags: angular, redirect, nginx, server, location

I'd like to deploy multiple angular applications that inherit from a principal application.

The main app is at the address: **myapp.com** (directory **/etc/local/nginx/html/myapp**)

The others apps should be at the following address:
**myapp.com/app_n** (directory **/etc/local/nginx/html/app_n**)

How could i configure that ?

I tried the following configuration but it didn't work:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    location /app_1 {
        alias /usr/local/nginx/html/app_1/dist;
    }

    location / {
        root html/myapp/dist;
        autoindex on;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

When the url is **myapp.com/app_1**, angular said "Page not found". In the **app_1**'s **index.html**, there is a script:

```
<script src="main.bundle.js">
```

When i inspected, i found that the **main.bundle.js** used by **app_1**, actually belongs to **myapp**. I though the reason is because the server name is **myapp.com**.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Have you tried `/main.bundle.js` (with a leading `/`)?

Comment: Problem is, the script tag is generated automatically by angular. And i don't want to modify any code in angular but only the nginx configuration file. Do u think that is possible ? Thanks !

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried to use "/main.bundle.js" but it didn't work. I must have to put "/app_1/main.bundle.js" to make it work, but i have about 100 applications like that...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a path-relative URI to access a resource file. The browser constructs an absolute path by looking for the last `/` of the current page's URL.

So, when using the URL `http://myapp.com/app_1` to access a page containing `<script src="main.bundle.js">`, the browser will look for a resource file at `http://myapp.com/main.bundle.js`.

If you use path-relative URIs, you must place the final `/` in the correct position, so both: `http://myapp.com/app_1/` and `http://myapp.com/app_1/index.html` will cause the browser to look for the resource file at `http://myapp.com/app_1/main.bundle.js`.